# How to add SVGPan support to raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

i'm using a library that creates svg content using raphael library. I would now like to add zooming functionality. I found following library:

http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/

This is how the svg part looks:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
//...the image
```

The issue is that this library expects a script tag and a g tag surrounding the whole image. It should look like this after manipulation:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<script xlink:href="SVGPan.js"/>
<g id="viewport" transform="translate(200,200)">
...//the image
</g>
```

I would need to add the script tag but the real problem is to put a g element with id="viewport" around the whole rest of the image. 
How can i do that with JQuery or plan JavaScript?

EDIT:

I got a bit ahead of myself. It turns out that adding the script tag does not seem to work:

```
var svg = $('svg'); 
svg.attr('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'); // else error in firefox with links
var scriptElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','script');
scriptElement.setAttribute('xlink:href','js/SVGPan.js');
svg.prepend(scriptElement);
```

I don't get an error and the script runs completely but the tag is not added. I have verified that $('svg') selects the desired element and I can do stuff with it except prepending the script tag for whatever resaon i do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Clafou for pointing me to raphael-zpd. This lead me to the solution.
The issue is that I was able to get the raphael object but zpd only works if nothing has been drawn yet which is not the case.

I'm using http://www.jsphylosvg.com which makes use of raphael. The solution is to edit the javascript file jsphylosvg.js directly:

1. search for this.svg = Raphael(sDivId, this.canvasSize[0], this.canvasSize[1]); (line 1217 in my case)
2. add: this.svg.ZPD({ zoom: true, pan: true, drag: true }); directly below that line
3. save jsphylosvg.js

done. It works!
(Of course you need to have a reference to raphael-zpd in your web page)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Raphael allows you to manipulate the SVG element but you could try a similar Raphael-specific library. This one may provide what you are looking for: https://github.com/semiaddict/raphael-zpd

Edit: Actually it is possible to manipulate SVG elements: Raphael exposes a Node property. So if you could get hold of the Raphael paper object you could try something like:

> paper.node.setAttribute("id", "viewport")

Comment: To be more specific I'm using a library that internally is using raphael. I have not yet figured out how to get the base raphael paper object to be able to manipulate it as for example with the zpd plugin.

Comment: it's not `paper.node`, it is `paper.canvas`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting it via a jQuery selector? You could for example try setting the id on the child g element by doing this (after your library has constructed the SVG element):

> $('svg > g').attr('id', 'viewport');

Comment: The thing is to get the g element around everything. it is not there at all! See Edit in my question.